# How to convert varbinary to varchar sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with columns :

```
ID int,
FirstName nvarchar(50),
Phone varchar(50),
Email varbinary(50)  -- (use varbinary for unicode)
```

Have stored procedure where I want update phone and email in this table .
This is input parametrs for my procedure

```
@id int,
@Phone varchar(50),
@Email varchar(50)
```

How convert Email to varbinary when update ? When I update like this :

```
UPDATE myProcedure
SET [Phone] = @Phone,
    [Email] = @Email
WHERE [ID] = @ID
```

Have error : `Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

Comment: "-- (use varbinary for unicode)" makes absolutely **no** sense when there are unicode datatypes built into SQL Server (`nvarchar` is one example). And especially if your procedure is accepting the input as `varchar` - anything not representable in the appropriate code page will have already have been lost before you start a conversion to `varbinary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you storing Email as `varbinary`?  Change it to [NVARCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) it will support Unicode 
fine.

Your table structure should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
   ID int,
   FirstName nvarchar(50),
   Phone varchar(50),
   Email NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

To convert:

```
DECLARE @ConvertedEmail VARBINARY(50)
SET @ConvertedEmail = CONVERT(varbinary(1000), @Email, 2)
```

You can then update your table using `@ConvertedEmail`

Comment: thank you for answering. but if it not difficult can you tell me how convert ? I convert like  convert(varchar,[Email]) = @email , but have an error